# Dictionnary value as String (and not NSString) in swift

Tags: ios, swift

This is really something I don't understand in swift:
It can be sumarized in the following code:

```
var dic: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = ["please": "show me the way"]
var way: String? = dic["please"] as? String
```

fails to compile and throws: *'String' is not a subtype of '(String, AnyObject)'*

however if I write the following code instead:

```
var way: String? = dic["please"] as? NSString
```

Everything is green. It's like `String` is not recognized as a subclass of `AnyObject` but `NSString` is.

So please show me the way :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed:

```
// error: Non-class type 'String' cannot conform to class protocol 'AnyObject'
extension String : AnyObject {
}
```

So you should use `Any` instead.

Comment: +1. `AnyObject` is a stand in for `id` which are Objective-C objects. `Any` is any object. It might also be better to declare the dictionary as var dic: [String: Any] = ["please": "show me the way"]` which is more modern Swift syntax. Or even to not declare the variable. It still works as Swift is type inferring.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `subscript` in `Dictionary` returns an optional:

```
subscript (key: KeyType) -> ValueType?
```

Meaning you have to unwrap the optional before you can downcast:

```
var dic: [String : AnyObject] = ["please": "show me the way"]
var way = dic["please"]! as? String
```

However I would suggest you wrap it around an if-let to make sure you don't unwrap nil values. You can read more about it in this post: http://tech.ustwo.com/2014/08/01/ios-swift-dictionaries/

Comment: This is not correct. Please see jtbandes answer and Anorak's comment.